# Is there a way to use Marshaller in Grails to parse JSON string into a custom object

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I am trying to parse a JSON String to my custom object
I already have a Marshaller class to go from the object to JSON
and was wondering if it possible to use it for parsing in other direction as well instead of using JsonSlurper
didn't see any clear documentation on that or any other JSON to object mapping api that is not includes writing code using  JsonSlurper to manually create objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groovy supports simple mapping like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

class A{
    int id
    String name
}

Map m = new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"id":123,"name":"Joe"}')
A a = m as A
assert a.id==123
assert a.name=="Joe"

def json = JsonOutput.toJson(a)
assert json == '{"id":123,"name":"Joe"}'
```

for marshalling/unmarshalling approach I prefer to use Gson library:

```
@Grab(group='com.google.code.gson', module='gson', version='2.8.5')
import com.google.gson.Gson

class A{
    int id
    String name 
}

A a=new Gson().fromJson('{"id":123,"name":"Joe"}', A.class)
assert a.id==123
assert a.name=="Joe"

def json = new Gson().toJson(a)
assert json == '{"id":123,"name":"Joe"}'
```